# Prove $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{-k^2 } < \prod_{k=1}^{n} (1+e^{-k})^{-1} $.

Tags: inequality

Prove $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} e^{-k^2 } < \prod \limits_{k=1}^{n} (1+e^{-k})^{-1}. $ 
Where can I start for the proof ?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: MathJax works in the title section

Comment: You can start by proving the case $n=1$ !

Comment: @JeanMarie 
I'm asking for method , any help will be appreciated .

Comment: This is part of the method !!! Even if it is not difficult to prove that  $e^{-1}<\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-1}}$, it is a first step that is necessary for beginning to "handle" the issue...

Comment: Moreover, the method behind this is working by recurrence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ n $ be a positive integer, we have :

\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{-k^2}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-n^{2}}}<\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{1-\mathrm{e}}}\leq\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-n}}{1-\mathrm{e}}}=\mathrm{e}^{-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{-k}}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-k}}}\leq\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-k}}}\end{aligned}

$ \bullet $ Note that : $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-n^{2}}}\simeq 0,386318<0,558792\simeq\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{1-\mathrm{e}}} \cdot $

$ \bullet $ Notice that $ \left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\right),\ \mathrm{e}^{x}\geq 1+x $, that was the inequality that we used in the last part, setting $ x=\mathrm{e}^{-k} $, then taking its inverse.